# Parse HTTP JSONObject response in java

Tags: java, http, post, json

From the endpoint "`test`" I am returning a `JSONObject`:

```
@POST("/test")
    @PermitAll
    public JSONObject test(String name) {
    JSONObject jsonval=new JSONObject();
    json.put("key1",true);
    json.put("key2","test");
        return json;
    }
```

in the method that checks the returned value I want to search for **value of "key1".**

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String json = null;
    String res = "";

    while ((res = in.readLine()) != null) {
        json += res + "\n";
        }
    in.close();

    if (jsonData has key1 with value true){
    //do sth
    }
    else{
    //do sth else
    }
```

How can I parse the returned JSONObject?

Comment: What's the jar that you are using for obtaining the class JSONObject?

Comment: json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried constructing the JSONObject from its string representation (see http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html):

`JSONObject result = new JSONObject(json)`

where `json` is the string you've read from the `InputStream`

Note: you might have to strip the last new line char or even omit new lines altogether